# Consider the set, recursively built, starting from the unit interval and removing the first $\frac{1}{3}$ at each step. Find the similarity dimension.

Tags: fractals, chaos-theory, cantor-set, nonlinear-dynamics

My thinking for this question is that it is just a slight variation of the standard Cantor set and will therefore have the same similarity dimension. My logic is that at each new step, the interval can be split into 2 copies of the previous one, each with a scaling factor of $\frac{1}{3}$ and therefore the similarity dimension is $\frac{\log 2}{\log 3}$.

Am I correct in my thinking here?

Comment: Your construction is unclear to me.  What are the first several iterates?  It seems that the first iterate is $[0,1]$ and that the second iterate is $[1/3,1]$, but what comes next?  $[4/9,1]$?  $[5/9,1]$?  $[4/9,2/3] \cup [ 7/9/1]$?  Something else?

Answer (score 2):

In fact this is not similar to the cantor set. At every timepoint you're reducing the size to $\frac{2}{3}$ of its previous size. This means we get $N=1$ copies of the previous one with a scaling factor of $\frac{2}{3}$.

That yields a dimension of $\frac{\log 1}{\log \frac{2}{3}} = 0$.

That's no surprise, as the set you described is not a fractal, it's just the limit of the interval $[\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{2^{i-1}}{3^i},1]$ which is $[\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{3}\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{2^i}{3^i},1] = \{1\}$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124306/discussion-on-answer-by-legnaib-consider-the-set-recursively-built-starting-fr).